# Show button alongside block of text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position my button to the right of my text. Unfortunately it keeps dropping to a new line. How do I resolve this?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vkp4q8cv/

Code:

```css
* {
  text-align:center
}

.eupopup-button_1 {
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #1588cb;
    color: #1588cb;
    font-weight: 400;
    position: relative;
    margin: 25px auto 50px auto;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -o-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    transition: color 0.1s linear;
    height: 60px;
    width:120px;
    display:inline-block;
    line-height: 60px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    z-index: 190;
    text-align: center;
}

.eupopup-closebutton {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: helvetica, arial, verdana, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="eupopup-container eupopup-container-fixedtop eupopup-color-default">
  <div class="eupopup-head">
    This site uses cookies to store information on your computer
  </div>
  <div class="eupopup-body">
  </div>
  <div class="eupopup-buttons" style="position: relative;">
    <a href="#" class="eupopup-button eupopup-button_1">Learn more</a>
    <a href="/cookie-policy/" target="_blank" class="eupopup-button eupopup-button_2"></a>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="eupopup-closebutton">x</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want the button to be just after the text (aka inline) or fixed to right side, close to the close button?

Comment: Apologies. Inline, just after the text would be brilliant :-)

Comment: I think you are making the structure too complicated for such a simple task but have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/vkp4q8cv/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make everything an inline block

```
.eupopup-buttons, .eupopup-head, .eupopup-body {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

I don't know if you ever plan on using the ..-body, because that would need a bit more changes